# What's the smallest data type in C that can store the number 10,000,000?

Tags: c, memory

I'm trying to celebrate 10,000,000 questions on StackOverflow with a simple console application written in C, but I don't want to waste any memory. What's the most efficient way to store the number 10,000,000 in memory?

Comment: In most cases `int`, but the C-language standard does not dictate the exact size of primitive data types, so it's really up to the compiler in use, which is usually designated for the underlying HW architecture that your program is running over. Include file `<limits.h>` in your code, and check the values of various preprocessor definitions (namely, `INT_MAX` and `LONG_MAX`).

Comment: How about `_Bool b = 1; if (b) printf("10 000 000")`?

Comment: @black The string constant "10 000 000" is wasting a lot more space in the data segment than an integer would. ;)

Comment: @Dan this must be a fascinating console app if you're tossing a string yielding 11 bytes in favor of a code segment needing to xlat a binary representation to the console. Or was your intent to simply declare a var and `return 0;` ?

Comment: Assuming that you have a large array containing these values (otherwise, the entire question is rather irrelevant, since memory consumption is not an issue): If you're willing to "pay" in runtime performance (number of operations during execution),then you can "squeeze" each value into 3 bytes.

Comment: Without specifying the resolution you want (I'd assume all integers from 0 to 10M), the question isn't complete. I could define a format that increments in 1e7 steps per LSB, then could do it in 1 bit. Or say I have a floating point number format that has 0 bits of significand (always 1) and 3 bits of mantissa (power 10).

Comment: @NickT This question would have been more interesting if he specified contraints, requirements, and told us to design some way of representing number...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number `10000000` (ten million) requires 24 bits to store as an unsigned value.

Most C implementations do not have a 24-bit type. Any implementation that conforms to the 1999 C standard or later must provide the `<stdint.h>` header, and must define all of:

```
uint_least8_t
uint_least16_t
uint_least32_t
uint_least64_t
```

each of which is (an alias for) an unsigned integer type with at least the specified width, such that no narrower integer type has at least the specified width. Of these, `uint_least32_t` is the narrowest type that's guaranteed to hold the value `10000000`.

On the vast majority of C implementations, `uint_least32_t` is the type you're looking for -- but on an implementation that supports 24-bit integers, there will be a narrower type that satisfies your requirements.

Such an implementation would *probably* define `uint24_t`, assuming that it's unsigned 24-bit type has no padding bits. So you could do something like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#ifdef UINT_24_MAX
typedef uint24_t my_type;
#else
typedef uint_least32_t my_type;
#endif
```

That's still not 100% reliable (for example if there's a 28-bit type but no 24-bit type, this would miss it). In the worst case, it would select `uint_least32_t`.

If you want to restrict yourself to the predefined types (perhaps because you want to support pre-C99 implementations), you could do this:

```
#include <limits.h>

#define TEN_MILLION 10000000

#if UCHAR_MAX >= TEN_MILLION
typedef unsigned char my_type;
#elif USHRT_MAX >= TEN_MILLION
typedef unsigned short my_type;
#elif UINT_MAX >= TEN_MILLION
typedef unsigned int my_type;
#else
typedef unsigned long my_type;
#endif
```

If you merely want the narrowest predefined type that's guaranteed to hold the value `10000000` on *all* implementations (even if *some* implementations might have a narrower type that can hold it), use `long` (`int` can be a narrow as 16 bits).

If you don't require using an integer type, you can simply define a type that's guaranteed to be 3 bytes wide:

```
typedef unsigned char my_type[3];
```

But actually that will be wider than you need of `CHAR_BIT > 8`:

```
typedef unsigned char my_type[24 / CHAR_BIT]
```

but that will fail if `24` is not a multiple of `CHAR_BIT`.

Finally, your requirement is to represent the number `10000000`; you didn't say you need to be able to represent any *other* numbers:

```
enum my_type { TEN_MILLION };
```

Or you can define a 1-bit bitfield with the value 1 denoting `10000000` and the value 0 denoting *not* `10000000`.

Comment: I guess the real question is that if you need to only store 10M, do you even need that 1 bit of information?

Comment: Storing "1" in memory and storing "10000000" in memory are **not** the same thing. The semantics of the name you've given your enumeration constant are meaningless to the computer. If the type definition requires pre-shared knowledge to determine the meaning of its contents, then it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Dan: I don't necessarily disagree -- but I'll make this point just to be contrary. Storing `1` in memory is not meaningful without some pre-shared knowledge -- in particular, `1` *what*? Bits in memory mean what we want them to mean. Having said that, the last part of this answer was not meant to be taken *too* seriously.

Comment: @KeithThompson I'll admit, the question was not meant to be taken *too* seriously either (I even tagged the question `SOreadytohelp`, but a vigilant party-pooper removed the tag). Nevertheless, I'm always impressed by the insane quality and educational value offered by the community in response to even the silliest of questions.

Answer (score 7):

The type you're looking for is `int_least32_t`, from `stdint.h`, which will give you the smallest type with at least 32 bits. This type is guaranteed to exist on C99 implementations.

Exact-width typedefs such as `int32_t` are not guaranteed to exist, though you'd be hard pressed to find a platform without it.

Comment: That "rare" platform you are looking for that doesn't have `int32_t` is called Windows.

Comment: @JustSid All the common Windows compilers (VC++, Intel, GCC) have came with standard libraries including `int32_t` for several years.

Comment: @JustSid: MinGW(-w64), Cygwin, Visual Studio, Pelles C, etc. all have `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: Does it actually? Last I checked it had only `std::int32_t`, which doesn't do much in the C world

Answer (score 3):

Technically a 24-bit integer can store that, but there are no 24-bit primitive types in C. You will have to use a 32-bit `int`, or a `long`.

For performance that would be the best approach, wasting 1 unused byte of memory is irrelevant.

Now, if for study purposes you really really want to store 10 million in the smallest piece of memory possible, and you are even willing to make your own data storage method to achieve that, you can store that in 1 byte, by customizing a storage method that follows the example of `float`. You only need 4 bits to represent 10, and other 3 bits to represent 7, and have in 1 byte all data you need to calculate `pow(10, 7);`. It even leaves you with an extra free bit you can use as sign.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store a number n > 0 in an unsigned integer data type, then you need at least ⌈lg (n+1)⌉ bits in your integer type. In your case, ⌈lg (10,000,000 + 1)⌉ = 24, so you'd need at least 24 bits in whatever data type you picked.

To the best of my knowledge, the C spec does not include an integer type that holds specifically 24 bits. The closest option would be to use something like `uint32_t`, but (as was mentioned in a comment) this type might not exist on all compilers. The type `int_least32_t` is guaranteed to exist, but it might be way larger than necessary.

Alternatively, if you just need it to work on one particular system, your specific compiler may have a compiler-specific data type for 24-bit integers. (Spoiler: it probably doesn't. ^_^)

Comment: Technically `uint32_t` isn't required to exist, so `int_least32_t` might be a better choice (or not).

Comment: @melpomene I did not know that. Answer updated. Thanks!

Comment: Upvoted for offering the general purpose solution `lg(n+1)`.

Answer (score 1):

The largest value that can be stored in an `uint16_t` is `0xFFFF`, which is `65535` in decimal. That is obviously not large enough.

The largest value that can be stored in an `uint32_t` is `0xFFFFFFFF`, which is `4294967295` in decimal. That is obviously large enough.

Looks like you'll need to use `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 1):

The non-smart-alecky answer is uint32_t or int32_t.

But if you're really low on memory,

```
uint8_t millions_of__questions;
```

But only if you are a fan of fixed-point arithmetic and are willing to deal with some error (or are using some specialized numerical representation scheme). Depends on what you're doing with it after you store it and what other numbers you want to be storable in your "datatype".

Comment: The "datatype" need not be able to represent any value other than 10,000,000.

Comment: Storing only one possible value requires zero bits, since there is only one possible value.

Comment: @void_ptr If you don't store anything, how is the consumer supposed to know whether or not a value is even present, let alone what the value is? You're assuming prior communication through external channels, which isn't part of the problem statement.

Comment: @Dan - You said it yourself, the datatype always represents a value of 10 million. Since it cannot represent anything else, there is nothing to store. And prior communication is _always_ a requirement. How, for instance, a consumer is supposed to know what a `float` format is, and how to interpret it? Answer - via prior communication.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct {
   uint16_t low;  // Lower 16 bits
   uint8_t  high; // Upper 8 bits
} my_uint24_t;
```

This provides 24-bits of storage and can store values up to 16,777,215.  It's not a native type and would need to special accessor functions, but it takes less space than a 32-bit integer on most platforms (packing may be required).

Comment: I like this answer, even though it's a bit impractical. A creative solution.

Comment: When you're working on a microcontroller with kilobytes of memory, it becomes eminently practical

Answer (score 0):

`uint32_t` from `<stdint.h>` would probably be your go-to data type. Since `uint16_t` would only be able to store 2^16-1=65535, the next available type is `uint32_t`.

Note that `uint32_t` stores *unsigned* values; use `int32_t` if you want to store signed numbers as well. You can find more info, e.g., here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html